# How to automatically add a dereferencing tooltip to eqrefs, footnotes etc.?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

Similar to what [Wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) when you hover over reference links

[image]

I would like the internal links placed by `hyperref` to automatically have tooltips containing the contents linked to, be that a reference, and equation, a footnote, maybe even a figure or whatever else. How can this be automatically achieved?

The minimum requirement for the tooltip is plain text, but correct math mode display would be really great. Graphics would merely be a nice-to-have.